# Running multiple clients from a single class in a chat server program

Tags: java

I have designed a server program and a client program for a simple java chat-server. The chat server runs and clients can pass messages to each other through the server.

However, I am having to create multiple copies of the same client class and number these classes as Client1, Client2, Client3, ... (i.e. in different names) in order for the server to accept connection from each of these client classes.

My question is this: is it somehow possible to create as many client connections as we want using only a  single client class running on my computer?

Comment: Please provide some code. Of course it is possible to create many instances of a class.

Comment: I can't paste the code here as it's a homework and my lecturer might check for plagiarism. But, I've taken your other advice and created multiple instances of the class from many different main programs which access the client class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not need different classes. 
I think you need to either run the Clients in different processes, i.e. start the same Main class multiple times, or run it in multiple Threads.